# Product thumbnail images are not displayed in backend after manual upload in magento 1.9.1

Tags: image, magento, admin, magento-1.9, backend

Image thumbnails are not visible in admin.

I have manually uploaded images for products in admin. Images are visible in frontend. But not displayed in admin.

It shows the text "roll over for preview", when rolled over it just become empty.

Changed media folder permission to 777. and I have removed .htaccess file from /media folder too...

[Plz see the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7znRw.png)

But the thumbnails are visible for existing products.

[This is the existing product page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ogRU.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be caused by wrong permissions set to uploaded files.
Open `lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php` and make sure following permission are set:

Around line 219:

```
chmod($destinationFile, 0666);
```

Around line 541:

```
if (!(@is_dir($destinationFolder) || @mkdir($destinationFolder, 0777, true))) {
```

Note: This issue will also be fixed by applying patch `SUPEE-7405 v1.1`

Answer (score 3):

**Try This below Solution**

> Open up the following file:

```
lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
```

> Find this line :

```
 chmod($destinationFile, 0640);
```

> Replace it with this line:

```
chmod($destinationFile, 0777);
```

Answer (score 1):

increase your memory limit from php.ini or you can ask to your server support

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

no need to clear magento cache

Answer (score 0):

add below code in php.ini file on root

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

in admin panel go to admin->system->cache management and click Flush Catalog Images Cache